# VC++ 2015: std::move on unique pointer runtime assertion failure

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, unique-ptr

I  just started going through Anthony Williams' book "C++ Concurrency in Action" and so I tried out some stuff.

I created a class that is basically just a container for a std::string:

```
class stringTest {
public:
    stringTest(std::string& text) : text{text} {}
    void operator() () const { std::cout << text << std::endl; } 
    void changeText(std::string&& newText)
    {
        this->text = newText;
        newText = std::string{ "here we go" };
    }
private:
    std::string text;
}; 
using bigObjectPtr = std::unique_ptr<stringTest>;
```

Now I wanted to start a new Thread with the function processObject and use std::move to move the unique pointer to the new thread.

```
void processObject(bigObjectPtr object)
{
    object->changeText(std::string{"bla"});
    object->operator() ();
}

int main()
{
    stringTest text{ std::string{"this is a test"} };

    bigObjectPtr object{ &text };
    std::thread t{ processObject, std::move(object) };
    t.join();

    return 0;
}
```

This code will compile just fine but I get a runtime error:

```
Debug Assertion Failed!
...
File: minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\heap\debug_heap.cpp
Line: 892

Expression: is_block_tpye_valid(header->block_use)
...
```

I did some changes and found out that I get the same error if I just call processObject instead of starting a new thread and the error message only appears when calling operator(), changeText works just fine.

Could you tell me why this error message is appearing here and where I did something wrong?

Thank you,
Max

Comment: You can't make a `unique_ptr` to something on the stack. That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: What @T.C. said and consider [std::make_unique](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) if your compiler supports C++14.

Comment: @T.C. You can, but it's rarely useful.

Comment: Ouh man, I feel so stupid right now. Right everything works as expected when allocating the stringTest object on the heap... :/ Thank you

Comment: @DanielJour ...with the default deleter. /sigh

Comment: Your `changeText` looks fishy. Why do you assign to `newText`? If you change the previous assignment to use `std::forward` and thus possibly move semantics, then you get undefined behaviour.

Comment: @T.C. sorry, I'm just a bit pedantic ;)

Comment: @DanielJour yes, I just put that there to be sure that std::ref really passes the arguments by reference and forgot to delete it, but of course you're absolutely right and I shouldn't use it like this in a real program.